# Implemeting Nginx as reverse proxy on an EC2 instance, for an Eclipse Che farm

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy

Looking for scaling [Eclipse Che](http://www.eclipse.org/che/) (a cloud IDE), I'm implementing a [Che Farm](https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/scaling). In short, a group of Eclipse Che instances behind a reverse proxy.

[image]

Ok, I'm implementing the reverse proxy using Nginx on an EC2 instance using Amazon Linux AMI, but I found this problem: Eclipse Che needs opened the port 8080 for the client and the range 32768-65535 for its workspaces (more info [here](https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/networking)).

So, I modified the `nginx.conf` file like this:

```
server {
    listen 32768;
    listen 32769;
    listen 32770;
    listen 32771;
    [...]
    listen 65534;
    listen 65535;

    server_name  http://eclipse.company.cxx;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://eclipse.company.local:$server_port;
    }
}
```

After restart nginx, I got this message:

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
nginx: [emerg] socket() 0.0.0.0:33786 failed (24: Too many open files)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Two questions, please:

1. Is this a valid approach for implement a reverse proxy in this situation?
2. If this is valid, how can I fix the error "Too many open files"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not sure about your environment, just as a hint: Is the machine in question publicly reachable? If so, implement authentication / authorization, or use a VPN.

  > If this is valid, how can I fix the error "Too many open files"?
- Probably, because it's listening to that many ports, your `nginx`, runs against limits, specifically the ones dealing with [file descriptor(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), which "[...] is an abstract indicator (handle) used to access a file or other input/output resource, such as a pipe or network socket [...]".
- To tune these limits:

  - Leverage the `nginx` directive [worker_rlimit_nofile](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_rlimit_nofile).
  - If this is not enough:

    - Change the system wide limit, which is stored in `/proc/sys/file-max`. To alter it run `sysctl -w fs.file-max=${your-new-limit}`. To make it persistent across reboots etc. edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`.
    - Change the user limit, which is stored in `/etc/security/limits.conf`: Inside there, put for example two lines reading:

      ```
      nginx soft nofile ${your-new-soft-limit} 
      nginx hard nofile ${your-new-hard-limit}
      ```